# Control size of points in netgraph in R

Tags: r, netgraph

In R, the netgraph() function takes a cex.points argument that controls the appearance of the points in the plot. Is there a way to scale the size of points through a variable in my .excel?

Thank u all

I don't know the arguments

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"my .excel"*. Please edit the question with a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Are you looking for `netgraph(net1, points = TRUE, cex.points = 3)`?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! In fact I was not clear. I would like the size of the point to be proportional to the number of observations in the single node (in my case the number of patients). Is there a way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean by "scaling the points by a variable in my Excel", and if you are unsure of the arguments, you could have a look at `?netgraph`.

Suppose you had a vector of point sizes like this:

```r
my_point_sizes <- c(1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 6, 2, 1, 1)
```

And a netmeta object like this:

```r
library(netmeta)

load(system.file("/data/Senn2013.rda", package = "netmeta"))

net1 <- netmeta(TE, seTE, treat1, treat2, studlab,
                data = Senn2013, sm = "MD", reference = "plac")
```

Then you can apply the sizes to the points like this:

```
netgraph(net1, points = TRUE, cex.points = my_point_sizes)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! In fact I was not clear. I would like the size of the point to be proportional to the number of observations in the single node (in my case the number of patients). Is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: Hi Derro. That's why it's good to include a reproducible example in your question. Could you perhaps type `dput(df)` into your R console (except change `df` to the name of your own data frame), then copy / paste the result into the question? (Obviously remove any patient identifiable data before doing so)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to plot the points with sizes defined by the data. Function `netmeta` is a list of S3 class `"netmeta"` and has two members `treat1` and `treat2`.

Base R function `table` can compute the frequencies but since they are the frequencies of two vectors, the two vectors must be combined to a 1-dim vector. This is done with `c()`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(netmeta))

data(Senn2013)
net1 <- netmeta(TE, seTE, treat1, treat2, studlab,
                data = Senn2013, sm = "MD", reference = "plac")

# points size proportional to data frequencies
pts_size <- table(c(net1$treat1, net1$treat2))

netgraph(net1, points = TRUE, cex.points = pts_size)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>